# Using Twisted and Python to create a Router

Tags: python, python-2.7, tcp, proxy, twisted

When a client (ie. web browser) points to `localhost:8080`, its request should be sent to an address defined by `SERVER_ADDR` such as `http://www.yahoo.com`. It's more like a router or load balancer, than a proxy.

**Problem:** When my web browser points to `localhost:8080`, nothing is returned to it. On the Python console, the HTTP request header can be seen to have reached the Twisted app. Maybe this cannot be used for redirecting the browser's request?

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor

LISTEN_PORT = 8080
SERVER_PORT = 80
SERVER_ADDR = 'http://www.yahoo.com'

class ServerProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    def __init__(self):
        self.buffer = None
        self.client = None

    def connectionMade(self):
        factory = protocol.ClientFactory()
        factory.protocol = ClientProtocol
        factory.server = self

        reactor.connectTCP(SERVER_ADDR, SERVER_PORT, factory)

    # Client => Proxy
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print 'Data received from Client:'
        if self.client:
            self.client.write(data)
        else:
            data = data.replace('localhost:8080', SERVER_ADDR)
            print data
            self.buffer = data

    # Proxy => Client
    def write(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)



class ClientProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.server.client = self
        self.write(self.factory.server.buffer)
        self.factory.server.buffer = ''

    # Server => Proxy
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print 'Data received from Server: '
        print data
        self.factory.server.write(data)

    # Proxy => Server
    def write(self, data):
        if data:
            self.transport.write(data)



def main():
    factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
    factory.protocol = ServerProtocol

    reactor.listenTCP(LISTEN_PORT, factory)
    reactor.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is not a HTTP PRoxy; but rather a plain old TCP Proxy or "Port Forwarder". You need to implement HTTP if you are going to be intercepting HTTP.

Comment: @JamesMills I intend to create a TCP proxy/forwarder, but what will be an easy way to test that its working? Thought a webbrowser will work, but apparently it wont?

Comment: Test with telnet. A Web Browser talks HTTP. If you want to redirect/intercept HTTP traffic you need to do so with a Web Proxy (HTTP Proxy) otherwise a ``GET http://www.google.com/`` that gets transparently reconnected at the TCP level to ``yahoo.com`` will not work as the Yahoo Web Servers will probably return a 404 or some other error.

Answer (score 0):

It partially works for me: I get an HTTP error 400 bad request from the Yahoo server in my browser when I visit `http://localhost:8080`. This is because you're replacing the `Host: localhost:8080` section of the GET request with `Host: http://www.yahoo.com` and the protocol here is invalid. It should just be `Host: www.yahoo.com`.

That said, it then responds with a `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` redirect and it you run into other problems.

Edit: you should take a look at the proxy example on the twisted website (https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.3.0/web/examples/#auto2) and dive into the source to see how it's implemented.

```
from twisted.web import proxy, http
from twisted.internet import reactor

class ProxyFactory(http.HTTPFactory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return proxy.Proxy()

reactor.listenTCP(8080, ProxyFactory())
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Thank you! My intention is to create a TCP proxy but was using a web browser thinking its the easiest way to test. The code seems to work when tested with Telnet and a TCP software. However when the server is restarted, the TCP software does not notice the disconnection and remains connected to the proxy but not reconnecting to the server. Are we missing something?

Comment: @Nyxynyx If you want to pass through all TCP packets (such as SYN, ACK), you'll need to intercept them at a lower level, and I don't think twisted will be suitable. Take a look at "Basic NAT" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#Basic_NAT) it sounds like what you might after.